# printing prime number in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

hi i am new to programming and currnetly learing bash script.
please help with this error  " line 28: expected `)' "

Given below is my program.

```
read -p "enter the number:" a
while [[ $a -le 100 ]]
do
echo "$a"
if [[ (($a-1) % 2) -eq 0 ]]
then
((a++))
fi
done
```

Comment: Um, I feel a bit stupid for asking, but: Which of these lines is line 28?

Comment: and I think you're confusing shell programming with other languages. A lot of what you wrote *just doesn't work like that*. So, honestly, you need to go back and read an introduction: you trying to write Python or C and hope your bash think it's valid bash: not going to work, and us telling you that for every line you did that is just a bit of an unfair consumption of our time.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic evaluation in bash uses `$(( ... ))` so your test would need to be

```
if [[ $((($a-1) % 2)) -eq 0 ]]; then ...
```

but variable expansion is implicit in an arithmetic context, so you could write that as

```
if [[ $(((a-1) % 2)) -eq 0 ]]; then ...
```

**However**, there's really no need for the outer test brackets here, since you can use the status of an arithmetic expression directly:

```
if (( (a-1) % 2 == 0 )); then ...
```